# How to search particular contact from nsarray of nsarray

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, nspredicate

I have store the contact in alphabetical order so I have array of array for contact list which i have display on screen. Now i want to search the contact via name but predicate not work properly here. I have done below code.

```
   filterArray.filterUsingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "ANY SELF.name CONTAINS[cd] '\(tfSearchBar.text!)'", argumentArray: nil))
```

In filter array first i have all contact but when i search for "a" it gives all the section array which has "a" in the contact name. but here i have stuck. It is not necessary that the all contact of the section contain "a" in the contact name.

For example

```
(
    A:(
        {
            name = "abc"
            number = "123456"
        }
        {
            name = "azx"
            number = "123456"
        }
      )
)
```

For example for above example after search for "a". when i search for "ab" then same array return by predicate.Not only first object. Any way to find only first object with out nested predicate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the word "ANY" in your predicate but it seems redundant.  This code works as you describe when put into a Playground:

```
import UIKit

@objc class DataElement : NSObject {
    let name : String
    let number : String

    init(name : String, number : String) {
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
    }
}

let dataArray : NSArray = [
    DataElement(name: "abc", number: "123456"),
    DataElement(name: "azx", number: "689101")
]

let searchTerm = "a"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name CONTAINS[cd] '\(searchTerm)'", argumentArray: nil)

dataArray.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
```

Comment: This is array of the dictionary not a arrays of arrays. I want a contact from array of array